# How to import permissions module on react native project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, permissions

I'm new at react native and typescript.I wanna create permissions module for my react native project and I seperated two links at below [Yonah's project](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) and [Facebook's permissions project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid.js)

Additionaly

> npm install ,npm start , yarn run build --watch and react-native run-android

command running smoothly but permission module dont use it ,I dont present this module add my project.
And my trying link at below ;

```
const permission = require('react-native-permissions')
import React from 'react'
import {
StyleSheet,
TouchableHighlight,
Text,
View,
Alert,
AppState,
Platform,
PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native'

interface Props {
names: string[]
}

interface PermissionsState {
status: PermissionStatus
}

type PermissionStatus = 'granted' | 'denied' | 'never_ask_again' | ''

export class permissions extends React.Component<Props, PermissionsState>
{
constructor(props: Props, context: any)
// tslint:disable-next-line:brace-style
{
    super(props, context)

    this.state = {
        status: '',
    }
}

public render()
// tslint:disable-next-line:brace-style
{
    return (<View> a </View>)
}
 }

 async function requestCameraPermission() {
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,

    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // console.log("kamerayı kullanabilirsiniz")
    } else {
        // console.log('kamerayı kullanamazsınız')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // console.warn(err)
  }
  }

  export default permission
```

Answer (score 0):

requestCameraPermission function is not call. You can try to call function in

```
 constructor(props: Props, context: any)
 // tslint:disable-next-line:brace-style
 {
    super(props, context)

    this.requestCameraPermission= this.requestCameraPermission.bind(this);

    this.state = {
       status: '',
    }
 }

 componentWillMount () {
   this.requestCameraPermission();
  .....
 }
```

for multiple request see this example

```
export async function requestForPermission() {
try{

const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
  [
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,

    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,

    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  ],

)

........

} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}
}
```

@++

Comment: componentWillMount getting an error which is [ts] Cannot find name 'componentWillMount'.
any

Comment: and have I need this method ,constructor is same acting as far as ı know

Comment: Oh i'm sorry put componentWillMount function into class :D

Comment: my code is like this at now but still dont work permission yet,                        https://i.hizliresim.com/G0gQdV.png                                                              https://i.hizliresim.com/XXj7Vj.png

Comment: You have include your component into main script ?

Comment: I have not main script but I imported like tahat import permissions from '../../utility/Permissions'